# Powershell get ProductType on Workspace

Tags: windows, powershell, workspace

I have a Win10 desktop installed on Win2019 as Workspace.

If I try to get the ProductType through a PS command:

(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).ProductType

I receive 3 (VER_NT_SERVER) instead 1 (VER_NT_WORKSTATION).
Is it correct this behaviour or there is something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: The [workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/workspace/info) tag doesn't seem relevant your question. Please use a relevant tag or create one.

Comment: What is the result of running the code?

Comment: The result is 3